# China visa free entry with Turkish stamp in passport

Tags: visa-refusals, china, turkey

I've read a lot of stories that people with Turkish stamps in their passports get rejected at the airport in China. There's a few connecting flights which are really affordable from the UK, but unfortunately we have Turkish visits.

Is this information still accurate?

What I really can't understand is if this is the case, how there are loads of flights from Istanbul to Chinese airports, including some Chinese airlines. Surely if they are rejecting people with links to Turkey, they would have to reject the whole flight?

Comment: Where are you reading these stories?

Comment: Lot of reports. https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g294211-i642-k10985265-o50-Chinese_Visa_refusals_due_to_Turkish_visas_stamps-China.html

Comment: @Martin I found those threads. They all start with 'I heard that...'. Those people that appear to confirm the story have no idea whether it's the Turkish stamps that caused the problem, or some other issue. It looks like confirmation bias to me. They seem to be balanced with a similar number of people with Turkish stamps that _have_ received their visas. I'd look for policy guidance on the Chinese embassy web sites.

Comment: https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/china-visa-shanghai-beijing-tianjin-transit-cruise-passengers-a9189436.html - there's also this and https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Visa_trouble#China

Comment: The Wikivoyage entry on China doesn't appear to have been updated since 2017. The Independent article paints a picture of arbitrary refusals. I find the idea of a 2yo being refused when the parents were admitted nonsensical so exactly how much credence you can give such reports is debatable. Their reference to Turkey is a vague 'Some reports...'. On the basis of what I've seen I'd conclude only that getting into China is something of a lottery.

Comment: Just dont do visa free, get a normal visa beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, I have Turkish stamps and I fly in and out of China at least 10 times per year.

My wife has tiramisu stamps and do the same

Answer (score 1):

This did happen to me in October 2019. I was flying from UK to Japan via China. When I arrived in China we had been delayed and missed the connecting flight. The airline advised that they would provide me with a hotel and a new flight the next day. I had to go to the Visa desk so that I could leave the airport on a 24 hour visa, however they stamped a red stamp next to my Turkey Visa, and said "no entry". I asked why this was and what I should do and they shouted at me to leave the desk and "no comment". I had to stay in the airport building until my flight the next day which was not fun! So to those syaying this isn't true, just becauase it didn't happen to you doesn't mean it doesn't happen. There were about 4 or 5 of us on the same flight that this happened to, all of us had the Turkish Visa stamp all now with a red stamp from China next to it.